# Вызов своей функции в aiogram

Tags: python, функции, aiogram

Как вызвать свою функцию?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def load_qwes(message: types.Message):
    id_user = message.from_id
    bodymessage = sql_words(f'SELECT Infinitive, Past_Simple, Participle, Перевод FROM words WHERE '
                            f'[{id_user}]  IS NULL LIMIT 1')
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=id_user,text= f'новые слова \n{clear_text(bodymessage)}')


async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("11:22").do(load_qwes(???))
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def on_startup(dp):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp,on_startup=on_startup)
```

Если писать в аргумент?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Вам для отправки сообщения не нужен message, вам нужен только id_user. Сделайте отдельную функцию (без декоратора `@dp.message_handler()`), параметром которой будет этот id, ее и добавляйте на запуск через scheduler. Но естественно нужно откуда-то узнать id нужного пользователя (например, при старте бота сохранять id пользователя в базу, потом перед отправкой сообщения из базы доставать это id).

Comment: В итоге именно так и сделал), и ваш комент пришел. Я правильно понимаю, что вызвать функцию как я хотел в начале, невозможно?

Comment: Возможно: можно подсунуть какой-то фейковый объект Message, но в этом нет особого смысла, тут же не обработка пришедшего сообщения идет.